# Change Theme Attribute at Runtime

Tags: android, android-styles

I would like to change the attribute of a custom theme at runtime, if possible.

```
<resources> 
  <style name="MyTheme" parent ="Theme.Material.Light">
   <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

To set `textcolor` depending on background color for all views.

If that is not possible, is there a way to create a Custom Theme class(not as XML, as code), and change the color depending on some conditions.

Comment: Will the color be created dynamically or is it limited to e.g. black/white?

Comment: I would like to do the Generic approach to not limit it to black and white, but for my current purpose black/white would be enough.